# The Fourier transform of $\sin(x)\,\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$

Tags: fourier-transform

Can someone please find the Fourier transform of $x \mapsto \sin(x)\,\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$?

---

I know that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \sin(x)\, e^{-ipx} \,\mathrm dx = 2i\,\frac{p\sin(1)\cos(p)-\cos(1)\sin(p)}{p^2-1},
$$
but when I try to calculate the inverse Fourier transform
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{p\sin(1)\cos(p)-\cos(1)\sin(p)}{p^2-1}\, e^{ipx}\,\mathrm dp
$$ with Jordan, I arrive at the conclusion that the integral is zero, because the residues of the function are zero. Can someone help me to solve the integral and return to the beginning function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you really supposed to find the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $\sin(x)\operatorname{rect}(x/2)$? According to what you write in your first question you are supposed to find the inverse Fourier transform of $\sin(x)\operatorname{rect}(x/2).$

Comment: Note that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms of the factors. Please also tell us which convention of the Fourier transform you are using.

Comment: Please provide a definition of $\mbox{rect}$

Answer (score 1):

Informally, using that $\widehat{f \cdot g} = \hat{f} \ast \hat{g}$ (Fourier transform of product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms of the factors) and that
$$
\widehat{\sin}(p)
= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) e^{- i p x} \, \text{d}x
= \pi i \left(  \delta_{- p - 1} - \delta_{1 - p} \right)
$$
and
$$
\widehat{\text{rect}\left(\frac{\cdot}{2}\right)}(p)
= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \text{rect}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) e^{- i p x} \, \text{d}x
= \int_{-1}^{1} e^{- i p x} \, \text{d}x
= 2 \text{sinc}(p)
$$
we obtain
$$
\widehat{\sin \cdot \text{rect}\left(\frac{\cdot}{2}\right)}(p)
= 2 \pi i \left( \text{sinc}(- p - 1) - \text{sinc}(1 - p) \right).
$$